# question on sealed properties

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi i have 2 questions on the code below. Could you help to explain to me?

1) Why do we need sealed for this dataaccess class?
2) Why do we need singleton for this connectionstring?

New Approach

```
namespace DataAccess
{   
  //Singleton implementation to return the same BooksRepository   

  public sealed class Repository
  {

    static BooksRepository _bookRepository = null;
    static string connectionString;

    private Repository() { }

    public static void ConnectionString(string cs) { connectionString = cs; }

    public static BooksRepository BookRepository(Boolean create)
    {
      if (connectionString == null) 
        throw new ApplicationException("Need to set connection string for Repository");
      if (!create && _bookRepository != null) return _bookRepository;
      else
      {
        _bookRepository = new BooksRepository(connectionString);
        return _bookRepository;
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Apply in UI
`Books = Repository.BookRepository(false).GetAllBooks();`

**-------------------UPDATE ------------------------------------------------**
**** Old Approach**

This is what i practice for most of my projects. Isn't it more easier and simple than doing declaring the singleton concept as the above?

```
public partial class ZebraDataContext
{
    public ZebraDataContext()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ZebraConnString"].ToString())
    {
    }
}
```

In my Class

```
  public void Add()
    {
        using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (ZebraDataContext db = new ZebraDataContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    db.Stocks.InsertOnSubmit(this);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                    Logger.Error(typeof(Stock), ex.ToString());
                    throw;
                }
            }
            ts.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) [cause you don't want outsiders to break it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw(v=VS.100).aspx), 2) because you don't know better. [Singletons are evil](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/).

Comment: Could you give me a scenario which how does the outsiders can break it ? So when u say Singletons are evil, does it meant that the code above should not use the singleton?

Comment: Singletons have their uses. And sealed means no other class can inherit from this, and overwrite functionality. So sealed stops this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sealed class is to ensure no one inherits from this class. This also makes the class more performant due to JITer optimizations.
2. You don't need an instance of the ConnectionString for every instance of the Repository object so it has been made static.

Answer (score 1):

1)The sealed keyword is used to make it so the class cannot be extended.  Whoever wrote the class decided that they needed to prevent people from extending and modifying the behavior.  Without a greater context it is impossible to answer the question in any more detail than that.

2) `ConnectionString` is not a singleton, it is static.  The `BooksRepository` that is returned by the `BookRepository()` method is a singleton (or attempts to be really).  Again without a greater context it is impossible to say if it needs to be a singleton.  The reason you would use a singleton in this situation is if you want to ensure that everywhere  in the application uses the same `BooksRepository` object.   I'm assuming that the writer was trying to ensure the same connection string would be used to connect to the `BooksRepository` throughout the application.

However, looking at how this is written it does not really obey the singleton pattern.  It appears you can create multiple `BooksRepository` by specifying a true for create in the `BookRepository()` method.  Any existing references to the previous objects would still exist and not change. If the connection strings were changed between calls to `BookRepository()` then there would be different connection strings through the application.

Comment: @Craig Suchanec: i have updated my question. i still wonder which is the best approach. should i change to singleton or use back my existing code. i still do not see how singleton can benefits me in my program.

Comment: @belinq I would recommend against using the original code as it is not protecting the values in the way it is seems to be intended to.  By the other code you posted it also appears there is already a singleton manager for the connection string so the use of the static value here really is not good because you are adding a place for things to be out of sync and duplicating data.  Your new approach is better (assuming you actually have a base class with a constructor).  I however can't make a judgement of it being the "best" approach without knowing the whole system in much greater detail.

Comment: @Craig Suchanec:`Your new approach is better` Do you refer this to public sealed class Repository ? What i hate most from my old approach is everytime i do CRUD i got to do this `   using (ZebraDataContext db = new ZebraDataContext())`, Could that new approach of using singleton and static good enough to handle this?

Comment: @belinq I think I am misunderstanding you.  Do you want to use the pattern in the BooksRepository or the one in ZebraDataContext?  The using pattern is what I would expect to see for most database accesses.  If the context actually has a connection in it you would would probably not want to use a singleton for it because then you could only have one connection in your application.

Comment: @Craig Suchanec: yup, i understood what you meant. i would actually want to know which approach is the best. If using the pattern in BooksReporsitory is better, then i would throw away the ` using (ZebraDataContext db = new ZebraDataContext())`. I felt it redundant too for writting ` using (ZebraDataContext db = new ZebraDataContext())` in every CRUD i do.

Comment: @belinq I cannot recommend you use the implementation in the BooksReposiotry there are just too many potential problems.  If you want to use a singleton (something I'd highly advise against for database accessors) you should ensure that you only create the object you are holding as a singleton reference once.  You want to use a singleton when you need to coordinate or manage through a single object.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the code you see is the pre .Net 2.0 way of creating a static class where the class cannot be instantiated or inherited.

In your case (from .net 2.0 onwards) it is effectively equivalent to (note the static class and removal of the private constructor)

```
  public static class Repository
  {

    static BooksRepository _bookRepository = null;
    static string connectionString;

    public static void ConnectionString(string cs) { connectionString = cs; }

    public static BooksRepository BookRepository(Boolean create)
    {
      if (connectionString == null) 
        throw new ApplicationException("Need to set connection string for Repository");
      if (!create && _bookRepository != null) return _bookRepository;
      else
      {
        _bookRepository = new BooksRepository(connectionString);
        return _bookRepository;
      }
    }
  }
```

Whether you should be using static for connections is another story. I would say at a minimum use `[ThreadStatic]` on your connection so it can support concurrency (multithreaded access to their own connection).

```
  [ThreadStatic] static BooksRepository _bookRepository = null;
  [ThreadStatic] static string connectionString;
```